# Visual Studio 2010 crashes when trying to set CssClass property

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, intellisense

Many times when I'm editing a `.aspx` file and type `CssClass=`, the Visual Studio IDE hangs then crashes with option to restart. Clearly this is happening while VS is trying to populate the Intellisense with available classes. Nine times out of ten I already know what class I want. Is there a way to disable Intellisense just on CSS classes? Or is there something else going on?

Specs: Windows 7 (basic theme, no Aero), Visual Studio 2010 Professional, Pentium 4 2.4 GHz, 2GB RAM

Comment: I've had this problem too and found someone already reported it on Connect. If anyone else have this problem, report it here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/555462/vs2010-rtm-intellisense-crash

Comment: Try using the standard video driver.

Comment: Try turning off the Visual Studio's video performance settings.

Comment: This is the only issue I have with VS2010, and it's a huge pain

Answer (score 8):

Try "Enable Insert attibute value quotes when typing" on Tool -> Options -> TextEditor -> HTML -> Formatting

For me, it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue before and while it's hard to determine precisely what is triggering your crash, I would recommend a few possible solutions. Hopefully one of these will work for you.

- Open Options->Text Editor->CSS->Miscellaneous and disable "Statement Completion"
- Also in the General section there are other "Statement Completion" options.
- Try closing the project, deleting the contents of the "bin" folder inside the Project folder (you might backup your project before), then re-open the project.
- As a last resort you can try creating a new project and re-importing the project & code files, or even repairing/re-installing VS.

Best wishes, Matthew